# Is it possible to load data from S3 to SQL Server using Matillion ETL tool?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, matillion

Is it possible to load data from S3 to SQL Server using Matillion ETL tool?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good use case for Matillion.  The Matillion tool works by ingesting source data into a cloud database, and then running the transforms inside the database.  There are 4 cloud databases supported: Snowflake, BigQuery, Redshift, and Synapse.

There are output components that can then output data to a target DB, but MSSQL is not currently supported (Azure SQL is).

I suggest looking at SSIS which has native support for MSSQL

Answer (score 0):

Matillion ETL can help you to

- Load data into its supported Cloud Data Warehouse (currently there are [five options](https://www.matillion.com/products/etl-software/) which are: Snowflake, Amazon Redshift, Google BigQuery, Microsoft Azure Synapse, and Delta Lake on Databricks)
- Transform and integrate that data inside the Cloud Data Warehouse

MSSQL is not among the list of Matillion ETL supported Cloud Data Warehouses, so you can't use it to *directly* load data from S3 to MSSQL.

However you could use a [Microsoft SQL Server Output](https://documentation.matillion.com/docs/9041587) component to transfer data into MSSQL, provided it went via one of the above listed supported Cloud Data Warehouses first.